# What's going on in the opening sequence?

Tags: rayman-origins

The opening sequence of Rayman Origins wasn't particularly easy to interpret, particularly since this game appears to have much less dialogue than past Rayman games.  Does anyone know what exactly happened in this opening sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it looks like Rayman and his buds are relaxing in the Snoring Tree, but their relaxation angers some very old skeleton people living under the tree.  Despite the elderly lady's attempts to quiet the relaxing Rayman and team, they continue to annoy her.  She bangs on the tree, as if they were her upstairs neighbors in an apartment, but they continue to snore and enjoy themselves.  She starts throwing things at them, including (accidentally) her husband's head.  This freaks the friends out, and the old woman arrives, thinking they've stolen her husband's head.  A melee ensues, and the old woman captures Rayman and his friends, locking them up.  Rayman escapes, and goes about trying to free his trapped friends.